# use java to mock concurrently update count

Tags: java, java-8, java.util.concurrent

My colleague told me that in high concurrency mysql could not process update correctly, e.g.

```
update product set count = count - 1 where id = ? and count > 0;
```

maybe have count less than 0, I think he is wrong, so I wrote below code to prove this.

```
    int nThreads = 140; //less than max_connections  151 
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
    CountDownLatch startLatch = new CountDownLatch(nThreads);
    CountDownLatch endLatch = new CountDownLatch(nThreads);

    for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
        pool.submit(() -> {
            startLatch.countDown();
            try { startLatch.await(); } catch (Exception e1) { } //waiting for all task is submitted to guarantee concurrency

            String sql = "update t set count = count-1 where id =1 and count>0";
            try {
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                Statement stat = connection.createStatement();
                stat.execute(sql);
                endLatch.countDown();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
    endLatch.await(); //waiting for all task is done
    System.out.println("done");
    System.exit(0);
```

I'd like to know my above code is could mock high concurrency correctly? and if could simplify above code by java8?

Comment: You may open the connection and use `prepareStatement` before waiting for the latch to let the actual execution run as concurrent as possible. Don’t forget `commit` and proper resource closing, as otherwise, it’s not the database’s fault if updates get lost…

Answer (score 1):

It is not right that mysql can't update data correctly.

MySql lock the record for the update until the transaction is terminated, so no other thread can try to update it if the previous transaction on the same record has not been finished.

Comment: Thanks! But I want to know my code if could mock concurrently update db as in real world, and if could simplify my code by adopting java8 syntax